# Shared library: no version information available

Tags: c++, linux, linker

I'm working with Awesomium in linux, the SDK only provides a shared library: `libawesomium-1.6.3.so`. Some libraries on my machine have lower versions than what Awesomium requires:

```
$ ldd libawesomium-1.6.3.so

libawesomium-1.6.3.so: /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62: no version information available
 (required by libawesomium-1.6.3.so
```

So when I'm compiling with `g++ -lawesomium-1.6.3 ...` I will get errors like below:

```
libawesomium-1.6.3.so: undefined reference to 'jpeg_finish_output@LIBJPEG_6.2'
```

I know updating the jpeg library will solve the issue. But I don't have the root permission in the linux machine.

So I'm wondering whether there is a way to specify a relative path to a new `libjpeg.so` for `awesomium-1.6.3.so` to use.

**Update (cannot comment on the answers):**

I tried to add the `-L/path/to/new/libjpeg.8 -ljpeg` flags, the following warning shows up:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libjpeg.so.62, needed by libawesomium-1.6.3.so, may conflict
 with libjpeg.so.8
```

And the compiling still fails. I think the issue is, `libjpeg` is referenced indirectly by `libawesomium`, not directly by my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-L` option. But use it *before* `-ljpeg`!

Answer (score 0):

When compiling, use `-L` option as [fge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1093528/fge) said. But to run it, you will have to add the path to your library to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable (see §3.3.1 [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)).